# Editing table row cell swift 3

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I am trying to edit the table row cell. I have different tableViewController set up to display/edit the current events when they touch on the displayed events from initial tableViewController. Whenever I edit an event and hit save, it goes back to the main viewController where i am initially displaying my events, but it doesn't display the edited events. it keeps showing the original events.

Here is the portion of my main tableView file where i am displaying my events:

```
class EventsTable: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var tableData = ViewController()

@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!


@IBAction func saveToMainViewController (change:UIStoryboardSegue) {

    let editViewController = change.source as! EditEventsTableViewController

    let index = editViewController.index

    let titleString = editViewController.editedTitle

    tableData.eventsArray[index!].title = titleString

    table.reloadData()
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return tableData.eventsArray.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomeCell

    cell.eventTitle.text = tableData.eventsArray[indexPath.row].title

    cell.eventLocation.text = tableData.eventsArray[indexPath.row].location

    cell.eventDateAndTime.text = tableData.eventsArray[indexPath.row].date

    return cell
}

//function to delete cell and saves it
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        tableData.eventsArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        table.reloadData()

        let savedEvents = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: tableData.eventsArray)

        UserDefaults.standard.set(savedEvents, forKey: "savedEvents")

        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "edit" {

        var path = table.indexPathForSelectedRow

        let detailViewController = segue.destination as! EditEventsTableViewController

        detailViewController.index = path?.row
        detailViewController.eventsArray = tableData.eventsArray
    }

}
```

Here is the other tableViewController where i edit my data

```
class EditEventsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var txtEditTitle: UITextField!

var index:Int!

var eventsArray = [Event]()

var editedTitle: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    txtEditTitle.text = eventsArray[index!].title
}


 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0 {
        txtEditTitle.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "save" {
        editedTitle = txtEditTitle.text
    }
}
}
```

incase you guys need a better look at the project,
[download link](https://mega.nz/#!fM5mjIpI!vMC2_jh8Lst5v-y2BlY56KoTRDU4AGoWpr6YuZ2tdPk) for the project

Comment: I recommend to pass one particular `Event` – which must be a class –  to the Edit Controller and make the changes directly in the object. Then go back and reload the table view. Due to reference semantics the changes persist.

Answer (score 0):

Probably in `EditEventsTableViewController` you missed table view reloading?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.reloadData()
    txtEditTitle.text = eventsArray[index!].title
}
```

It's unclear, where do you provide data for `EditEventsTableViewController`. Is it static table view, designed in storyboard?